# Using FBNativeDialogs in an iOS 6 app

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

I'm implementing a feature where users can share photos on Facebook from an iOS app. The `presentShareDialogModallyFrom` method looks promising however I'm having trouble using it. Specifically I don't know what to `#import` if anything. Also I'm not sure if I need to add additional frameworks.

Integrating Twitter was pretty easy: just add the Twitter framework and import the relevant header file.

**What do I need to import/add to my iOS 6 app in order to use FBNativeDialogs?**

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Facebook SDK documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/), you should have `Social.framework`, `Accounts.framework`, and `AdSupport.framework` in your Linked Frameworks and Libraries. If you support any iOS below version 6.0, they should be Optional instead of Required.

In the class where you wish to use the `presentShareDialogModallyFrom` function, add `#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`.